# get text from NSTextfield in C#

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So I have a NSTextfield in Xcode and I am trying to grab the input text and save it as an integer in C# (working with Xamarin). I have spent the whole day looking for a solution, but failed.

Hour1 is the name of my textfield. I can't do like "Hour1.text". Can you help me?

```
int H1 = Convert.ToInt16(???);
```

Answer (score 3):

The NSTextfield should have a property called `stringValue` that contains the text as the normal .NET textbox control does.